# Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression. This expression is not callable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an error when I import DOCUMENT in IONIC 6 -angular :
the code below :

```
   import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; import { inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 
     import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core'; 
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
 export class ThemeService {
 private renderer: Renderer2; 
constructor( rendererFactory:RendererFactory2 , @inject(DOCUMENT) DOCUMENT: Document) 
{ this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null,null);}
```

the error message :
Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
This expression is not callable.
Type 'Document' has no call signatures.ts(1239)

(alias) const DOCUMENT: InjectionToken
import DOCUMENT

Comment: Do you still get that error if you change to @inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document

Comment: it works after adding  word "Private" to document: Document